# The type 'GunBehaviour' already contains a definition for 'gunRotation' error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a 2D platformer shooter and here is the code for the rotation of the gun. I tried to make the gun rotate towards the the mouse position so you could aim in the game, but I get this error message "The type 'GunBehaviour' already contains a definition for 'gunRotation'
"

```
        public Transform GUN;
        Vector3 gunRotation;
        Quaternion gunRotation;
        public Vector3 a;
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
         void Start()
          {
            a= new Vector3(mousePos.x,GUN.position.y);
            Quaternion q;
            Vector3 gunRotation = gunRotation.eulerAngles;
            Quaternion gunRotation = Quaternion.euler(gunRotation);
          }
         void Update()
          {
            gunRotation = GUN.rotation=(0f,0f,Mathf.Tan((mousePos-a).magnitude)/(a- 
            GUN.position).magnitude);
          }
```

Comment: Because the GunBehaviour already contains a definition for `gunRotation`.  :)  Either rename your Vector3 or your Quaternion.  In all cases.  Also, it's not gonna do what you think ;)  Google properties vs local variables

Answer (score 0):

This code is all wrong on a lot of levels. This script inherits `MonoBehaviour` or you wouldn't have `Start` or `Update`, and I would assume you're wanting to put this script on the gun itself, so you can update the gun.

In that case you can drop all of your stuff. Your (first) error is that you have two variables with the same name - this is your "already contains a definition" error. You'll also get an error in your gunRotation calculation in `Update` because you can't do `gunRotation = GUN.rotation =` .

What I think you're looking for instead would be something like:

```
public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{

    Camera mainCamera;
    void Start()
    {
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        Vector3 gunPos = mainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
        Vector3 diff = mousePos - gunPos;
        
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Rad2Deg*Mathf.Atan2(diff.y,diff.x)));          
    }
}
```

One of the problems you'd have doing it the way you proposed is that `Input.mousePosition` is in pixel/screen coordinates while any `transform.position` would be in world coordinates. Getting the main camera and calling `WorldToScreenPoint` is how you convert the GameObject's position to the same coordinates.

Once you're in a unified coordinate system you can then get the difference between mouse and GameObject positions in screen coordinates, and THEN you can do.. ARCtangent. Another bug in your code is that you're trying to take the tangent, which accepts an angle and gives you the ratio of sides in a triangle. What you want instead is the ratio of those sides (dx and dy) and to get the angle you need to rotate your gun. Another bug in your code is that `Mathf.Tan` and `Mathf.Atan2` expects/outputs angles in *radians*, but the `Quaternion.Euler` is going to expect those angles in *degrees*, so multiplying by `Mathf.Rad2Deg` gets you the proper conversion there.

If you've got any questions let me know. I copied the code I posted here to a script and ran it; here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: ok thanks a lot I am new to this stuff and wanted to try something without a tutorial.